# C# - How To Use A ref struct As A Generic Type Argument?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I am learning C# and trying to implement an interface that uses generics.
The interface is used within *System.Text.Json* custom converters.

Within the implementing class I am trying to pass a *Utf8JsonReader* as the type argument, (see code below).

The compiler gives an error message, that *Utf8JsonReader* cannot be used as a type argument. I think this is because it is a ref struct, which cannot be used as a type argument.

**Interface**

```cs
namespace WebApp.Data.Serializers.Converters.Visitors
{
    internal interface IVisitor<ReaderType>
    {
        MotionDetection DeserializeMotionDetection(ReaderType reader);
        MotionInfo DeserializeMotionInfo(ReaderType reader);
        MotionLocation DeserializeMotionLocation(ReaderType reader);
    }
}
```

**Class**

```cs
namespace WebApp.Data.Serializers.Converters.Visitors
{
    internal class JsonVisitor : IVisitor<Utf8JsonReader>
    {
        public MotionDetection DeserializeMotionDetection(Utf8JsonReader reader)
        {
            // implementation code
        }
        public MotionInfo DeserializeMotionInfo(ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
        {
            // implementation code
        }

        public MotionLocation DeserializeMotionLocation(ref Utf8JsonReader args)
        {
            // implementation code
        }
}
```

How can I work around this to implement the interface?

Comment: Please post the code for `IVisitor<T>` (a [mcve]).

Comment: @Groo Cheers, added code for IVisitor<T> interface

Comment: Oh, it's a `ref struct`? Yes, those are pretty restricted. There isn't a way to pass it as a generic parameter, since it's hard for the compiler to ensure that the generic class won't abuse it.

Comment: Cheers @Groo, Ok, looks like I will have to go down the route of using a non generic interface for the JOSN aspect. Thanks for prompt answer, appreciated.